# Field value updating stops after making a selection

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm working on a lead form and there's an annoying bug that I cannot seem to get my head around.

Every time  a change is made to certain fields a hidden field is updated to reflect this change. However, if you perform certain steps then the field stops updating itself and I have no idea.

JSfiddle wouldn't work with in element javascript so here's a test page: (link removed).

I have unhidden the field that automatically updates, its the one directly below the `textarea`.

Steps to reproduce:

- Select United States as origin country.
- Select any option from the "What are you shipping?" field.
- Select "ADD MY OWN DESCRIPTION" from the "Tell us more" field.
- Edit the textarea and unfocus the field to see the field below it
  update with its contents.
- Now, open the "Tell us more" drop down again and this time select any
  car make.
- A "Model" drop down will appear which you can select from or ignore
  to see how the "hidden" field updates.
- Go back to the "Tell us more" field and, once again, select "Add my
  own description".
- Edit the textarea to find the hidden field no longer updates itself.
- You have to select a make again, then reselect own description to
  force it to update with any changes made to the textarea.

How can I stop this from breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line `var strModel = model.options[model.selectedIndex].text;`

It's saying it cannot read the property `text` of undefined. Somewhere in your code you need to likely define the `model.selectedIndex`.

I see here you're defining the `make`'s in the `onblur` event:

```
info.onblur=function() {
    if (info.value=="") info.value=info.defaultValue;
    if (info.value!=info.defaultValue) {
        Show('quote_form_Make');
        BuildMakeSelect();
        make.selectedIndex = 2;
    }
}
```

When I select a make, and the model menu reads "Model", this is the result:

```
document.getElementById('quote_form_Model').selectedIndex // 0
```

When I select "Add your own description", this is the result:

```
document.getElementById('quote_form_Model').selectedIndex // -1
```

That should get you started in your debugging adventure.

Comment: Thanks AlienWebguy, I'll have to work on this later tonight. I'll post my results when I can!

Comment: I made sure that whenever the model `select` is hidden it also defines the `selected.index` of that element as 0. This seems to have fixed the issue. Couldn't have done it without you AlienWebguy! As an aside, how did you find that error?

Comment: IE8 has Developer tools (F12). I just had the console open in the Script tab and went through your steps to reproduce the issue. The error `Cannot read the property 'text' of undefined` told me the object wishing to hold said property hadn't been set, and since the variable part of it was the array key, it made sense for me to follow that lead.